# execv() did not work when in pass ( char * ) instead of ( char * const )

Tags: c

I have a program like blow:

```
int main()
 {
   char  * const args[2]={"a", "b",};

   int pid = fork();

   if ( pid == 0 ) {
      execv("./printargs", args);
}

return 0;
}
```

when I run it from terminal. execv() executes printargs and print all value of agrs[]. So the program works properly.

But when i change the program a little to take input and re-write the program like below:

```
int main()
 {
   char  * args[2];

   args[0] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
   args[1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);

   scanf("%s", args[0]);
   scanf("%s", args[1]);

   int pid = fork();

   if ( pid == 0 ) {
      execv("./printargs", args);
}

return 0;
}
```

then the execv() did not work & I did not understand what is the problem

but I need to pass args dynamically by taking value from input.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What means "did not work"? What happens?

Comment: Whatever read the execv manpage. The 2nd argument must be a NULL-terminated list. You don't terminate it by a NULL value (`args[2]=NULL;` and declare it as `char *args[3];`).

Comment: 'return 0' is fine for the parent, but probably wrong for the child.  If execv fails and the return is executed, that seems like a failure.  Since execv seems to be failing in your case, perhaps you should invoke `perror` after execv and let the system tell you why it failed.

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C! And `sizeof(char)` is useless/missleading, as it is guaranteed to always yield `1`.

Comment: Well in addition the manpage of `execv` stated that the 1st value in args is like the `argv[0]` of main: the name of the binary. So args must go into `args[1]`…

Answer (score 1):

So here as I said you have the following problems:

- `execv` needs as 2nd parameter a NULL-terminated array (so last value must be a NULL value)
- this parameter also starts with the "program name" so the real 1st parameter (as you intend it) is `args[1]` and not `args[0]`
- you also should check for errors and check for returned values
- beware that `%10s` means that `scanf` will read 10 characters max + add a leading `\0` after that, so it could be 11 characters! Use `%9s` or increase your allocation size

Here is a sample code that perform mostly the same (using `/bin/echo` command rather than `./prinargs`):

```
int main()
{
  char  * args[4];  // 1 for bin name, 2 for args, 1 for NULL
  args[0] = "/bin/echo";  // you may put what you want here, in fact
  args[1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
  args[2] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
  args[3] = NULL;  // NULL-terminated

  scanf("%9s", args[1]); // read 9 (+1 for \0)
  scanf("%9s", args[2]);

  int pid = fork();

  if (pid == -1) {  // handle fork() error
    perror("fork");  // print out the reason
    exit(1); // and leave
  } else if (pid == 0) {
    // child
    execv("/bin/echo", args);
    perror("execv"); // we are here only if execv failed
    exit(1);         // so print out error and exit
  }
  // here you should wait for your child to get returned value
  // see wait() and similar functions 
  return 0;
}
```

Most of the time it is better to wait for childrens (using `wait()` family) so that the father don't ends before the child(ren) and you can also get its return status (i.e. the return of the command you exec-ed or your `exit()` value if `execv()` failed.

Comment: I understood, and now It works for me, 
But I am facing another problem enhance my program.

Comment: If you have a new problem search by yourself and if you really can't find solutions ask an other question.